# Is it wrong to deduce the premise from the conclusion?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

My professor gave me the following argument to prove:

> Let $x$ be an even number. Then $x+x^2$ must be an even number.

I wrote down the following:

> Hypothesis: $x = 2n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$
>   Thesis: $x + x^2 = 2m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$
>
> Let us consider a direct proof.
>
> $x+x^2=2m$ (replacing $x=2n$)
>   $2n + 4n^2=2m$
>   $2(n + 2n^2) = 2m$ (since $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we can replace $m=n+2n^2$)
>   2m = 2m

My professor says I only proved the converse (that if $x+x^2$ is even, then $x$ must be even) I claimed that showing that I can reach an identity from any equation using the act that $x=2n$ suffices as a formal proof, but he wasn't convinced. How can I prove I'm right?

Comment: You're not entirely right, but your calculations also give rise to a direct proof: Let $m:=n+2n^2$.

Comment: What does "replacing $x = 2n$" mean?

Comment: As for the title of the question, the short answer is, "Yes."

Comment: You certainly haven't proved the converse, since the converse is false ($x+x^2$ is even whether $x$ is even or odd). But you haven't proved the desired result either. You've assumed both the premise *and* the conclusion, deduced something else ($2(n+2n^2)=2m$), and then asserted the trivially true equation $2m=2m$.

Comment: "How can I prove I'm right?"  You can't.  Because you aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1) Assumed the Conclusion $x+ x^2 = 2m$ 2)Assumed the Hypothesis $x = 2n$ and 3) Concluded an identity. $2m = 2m$.

Your professor is actually wrong.  You have not proven the converse (which isn't true).  You have actually done nothing.

You *can't* start from the Conclusion and prove a premise.

If $x + x^2 = 2m$ then $x(x+1) = 2m$ so one of $x$ or $x+1$ is even but we don't know which one.  For example.  if $x = 3$ then $x + x^2 =3+9 =12$ is even.

You *HAVE* to start from the premise:

$x = 2m$ and you can *!!!!!!!NOT!!!!!!* assume the conclusion.  You must *prove* the conclusion.

$x + x^2 = 2m + (2m)^2 = 2m + 4m^2 = 2(m + 2m^2)$ so $x+x^2$ is even.  QED.

Note, that if $x$ is odd then

$x = 2m + 1$ for some $m$ and

$x + x^2 = (2m + 1) + (2m + 1)^2 = 2m + 1 +4m^2 + 4m + 1 = 4m^2 + 6m + 2 = 2(2m^2 + 3m + 1)$ is ... even.

$x + x^2$ is always even whether $x$ is even or odd.

So you can certainly *NOT* assume the conclusion and prove the premise as the premise need not be true.

And even if it were.  You didn't prove anything.

Consider the false statment:  All even number are squares of even numbers.

So we start off assuming the conclusion: Let $M = (x)^2= (2m)^2$ a square of an  even number.  We take the square root so $x = \pm 2m$.  And therefore $x$ is an even number.

QED?

No. The statement was the exact opposite.

If $x = 2m$ is an even number then prove that $x= 2m = (2n)^2$ is a square of an even number.

We can not prove that because it is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the invalid statement: "Let $x$ be a bird. Then $x$ is a duck."

Now, your approach is to assume the consequent, that $x$ is a duck, then demostrate that the duck is a bird, and decide that the statement was valid.  Opps.

So, no, affirming the consequent is a falacy.

Answer (score -1):

sorry it's not clear if the universe of discourse is natural numbers or integers since you reference both.

Assuming integers:

if $ x $ even -> $ (x + x^2) $ even.

because you're given that x is even, pretend $ \exists i \in \Bbb Z (x=2i) $

you need to show that $ \exists j \in \Bbb Z  (x^2 + x = 2j) $

$$ x = 2i $$
$$ x^2 = 4i^2 $$
$$ (x^2 + x) = 4i^2 + 2i = 2j $$
$$ j = 2i^2 + i $$